# Use Javascript library loaded in parent HTML page in embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, charts

My application is using the ExtJS library to generate charts in Javascript. Unfortunately, as far as I've been able to tell from the examples and documentation online, ExtJS doesn't let you generate new charts without a page reload.

My pages will have a lot of charts on them, and I'd like to allow my user to change the chart type for a dataset without having to go through a page reload. My solution so far has been to make each chart inside of an embedded iframe, which allows me to reload a new type of chart in a new iframe without reloading the page.

The problem is that so far, I've had to load the ExtJS library in each iframe separately, which gets pretty slow when you're talking about 15 or 20 iframes. What I'd like is to be able to use the ExtJS library inside of my iframes without having to load the library for each one. When I used "parent" to access the ExtJS functions, it started acting up, mostly because of how ExtJS requires you to put your chart generation in their Ext.onReady() function (calling parent.Ext.onReady() gave some very strange behaviors).

Any ideas for solutions or workarounds? I would use another library, but I'm already migrating from an uglier, flash based chart library, and I really like what ExtJS is capable of.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems *very unlikely* that ExtJS forces a page reload to generate a new chart.

Comment: Trust me, I agree with you, and I'm still not 100% convinced myself. But after spending a lot of time trying various solutions, I was unable to generate a new chart outside of the onReady function, nor have I been able to find an example (on Sencha's site or elsewhere) where a chart is generated outside onReady. The primary solutions I've found have been to generate all possible charts and put them in a card-type layout, but that's epically slow for the number of charts I'm generating. If anyone finds an example please point me to it, I'd love to see how it's done.

Comment: From a forum posting by an Ext support team member, replying to someone else's question: "You haven't had [your code] on onReady? Only Ext.define statements are allowed outside onReady, all Ext.create and anything that accesses DOM has to be inside." Chart generation accesses the DOM... it's unfortunate, the library is SO GOOD for charts.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the future, perhaps in a defer, reload your [store.load()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load). If you use Direct you could use its own polling scheduler as well.

Comment: As I understand it store.load() would allow me to dynamically load a new dataset, but what I need is to dynamically generate a new chart type with the same dataset.